# figma dropdown menu shows options behind others components

Tags: position, dropdown, overlay, z-index, figma

my problem is when i click the select input and the option show behind the others select inptus.
[image]

its the same behavior with the other 2 select inputs, i think its a z-index problem or absolut position or something like that.

Each select is a component with variants.

I need that when i click a select input the options show in front of anyother component.

i tried to reverse all the variants or use auto layout but this one brake my visual disposition, [image]

Any help will be valued.

Answer (score 0):

Change the canvas stacking option to first on top

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).